# Каким образом исполняется программа в с++?

Tags: c++, компиляция

Писал лабу на с++, пользуюсь CLion, компилятор g++, система сборки Cmake.
Очень озадачило то, каким образом запускается программа. При запуске, идёт полный путь из домашней папки до файла crtlab1 (так называется программа), но если перейти в папку с самим файлом посредством какого-нибудь cd, то вводя имя файла окажется что он не является исполняемым (а у него попросту нет расширения), из-за чего выходит ошибка. Каким образом это работает?
Пример рабочей и нерабочей команды:

```
./cmake-build-debug/crtlab1
```

Из папки на уровень выше по иерархии, эта штука работает
Но если запускать непосредственно из папки cmake-build-debug

```
crtlab1
```

В таком случае ничего не работает. Надеюсь на какую-то полезную информацию или ресурсы, в которых можно почитать про это получше (системами сборки не владею, лишь самим языком с++, в процесс линковки компиляции не углублялся)

Comment: `./crtlab1` из той дериктории, в которой лежит файл.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы собираете исполняемый файл для подсистемы linux (WSL), или mingw какой ни будь ...

Comment: Никогда в жизни не чувствовал себя таким дураком, спасибо за ответ)
Но не отказался бы почитать о том, как собирать файлы, проекты, упаковывать в один цельный exe-шник и так далее, заранее благодарю

Comment: компилятор собственно и "упаковывает их в один исполнимый файл". Просто в линукс расширение не имеет значения и если очень сильно хочется, то можно переименовать в exe (правда от этого оно все равно не будет просто так запускаться (нужно через точку-слеш) )